# Ability to record web page within browser without any extension

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, screen-recording, recordrtc

I'm working on a POC to record webpage screen and send the recording back to server without any extensions or application software support. Tried various approaches but those are not meeting my requirement.

**Requirement in detail:** Need to record the web page without adding any extensions or application software.

**Application details:** Single page application developed with KnockoutJS

***Below are the approaches tried:***

1. RecordRTC ( https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/Canvas-Recording/ )
   But as we have duration of around 15 minutes for each recording, after 2 or 3 recordings browser is hanging or not reponding.
2. Screen recorder software's ( Ex: Apowersoft ) 
   To use these tools ( though tried with the API ) user needs to install application software. As we don't want user to do any installation I'm unable to use any such screen recorder
3. Using session recording/replay feature of Anaytics tools such as ( mouseflow, inpectlet ). If we observe **-> [link here](https://mouseflow.com/demo/)** this is exctly meeting my requirement. As a user we no need to install anything infact user is not aware of the recording happening. But the problem with these tools such as Mouseflow are not providing the download of recording as video file, Recording's are saved in their server and we can play only with their embed script.

I feel approach 3 is closer to my requirement but as i'm unable to download that recorded session as video file I'm unable to move further. can some one has idea of any tool which can provide recording as video file.

Please provide your thought/inputs how i can meet my requirements.

Comment: Sorry, how is this related to knockout?

Comment: @ray Yes, My intention is to give full background of application

Comment: @ChaitanyaSai Were you able to find a fix for your problem ? as i am looking for something close :|